# Select second item in list where value in dictionary follows condition

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following list of dictionaries:

```
l = [{'cycleIndex': 1, 'amount': 100},
     {'cycleIndex': 1, 'amount': 200},
     {'cycleIndex': 2, 'amount': 1000},
     {'cycleIndex': 2, 'amount': 2000}]
```

I want to print out `200` and `2000` which are the `values` in the second dictionary "`where`" `cycleIndex` is repeated.

I basically want to select a specific `value` for a given element (which are dictionaries in this case, hence "`value`") in a list, filtering by another `value` within that dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will keep track of the indexes, anything after the first occurrence of an index will be printed out.

```py
seen_indexes = set()
for d in l:
    index, amount = d['cycleIndex'], d['amount']
    if index not in seen_indexes:
        seen_indexes.add(index)
    else:
        print(amount)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `pandas` :

```
import pandas as pd

output = pd.DataFrame(l).drop_duplicates(subset='cycleIndex',keep='last').to_json(orient='records')
```

output :

```
>> [{"cycleIndex":1,"amount":200},{"cycleIndex":2,"amount":2000}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing it like this.

```py
for i in l:
    if i["amount"] == 200 or i["amount"] == 2000:
        # Do something
```